# jquery addclass not working on backbone event

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

addClass for jquery is not adding the 'active' yet is getting called (seen below, both console.logs do fire off)

```
events: {
    'click .nav-sidebar li': 'menuChange'
},

menuChange: function (ev) {
    $(ev.currentTarget).addClass(function() {
        console.log('Class added....supposedly');
        return 'active';
    });
    console.log('Selector!');
}
```

I was just adding the class like `.addClass('active')` but that wasn't working so I used the function with a console log to make sure it was reaching, even though I don't know why it wouldn't.

Also, it's not my css because I put a `debugger` in there and inspected ev.currentTarget in firebug and added the class by hand which it works fine. It's just not adding the class when clicking.

```
<ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li><a href="#/account/settings">Settings</a></li>
</ul>
```

The `<li>` should be having the active class added to it.

Comment: can you check what is `ev.currentTarget`

Comment: Are you sure that you create Backbone.View in the right way?

Comment: This is the best I can do to somehow represent currentTarget here
`currentTarget  li` 
    `type       ""`
    `value      0`
    `...`

Comment: Do you have a jsFiddle you can post?

Comment: I tried using jsFiddle but they don't have backbone there. I'll try to replicate it in pure jquery

Comment: @BuDen Yeah everything renders correctly and other events/functions are working

Comment: You can add any library you want to jsFiddle.  just open the External Resources tab and add this - //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.2/backbone-min.js

Comment: Seems to work, at least in this setup http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/4LuVS/

Comment: Yeah it is, what the heck why is it not working for me. Both console logs are hitting but I'm looking at the html right now and li definitely does not have active as a class

Comment: Have you tried a different class, just for the hell of it?

Comment: I think I've found the problem. The view is getting re-rendered somewhere and so even though active has been added, the page renders it back to the way it was before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that the links fire off a route change which is meant to render a subview but that route re-renders the entire page, removing any changes I made to the DOM and resetting to the default template effectively undoing my changes (adding the 'active' class).

Comment: That makes sense.  So you need to add the active class based on the route, after the page has been rendered.